# Remote git fetch asks for password

Tags: git

I am doing a git fetch from a remote ssh location. I did not set a passphrase while setting the key, it still asks me for password.

To get around this, I created a new key pair with a known Key passphrase. Then I entered that for the password (when prompted during fetch). It still doesn't let me in. What password is it expecting?

Update: I updated the repository with the SSH public key. But locally I just overwrote the old key. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: We need more information. Is your key actually even loaded? (ssh-add -L) is your key the one the other side has for you? What protocol are you connecting to remote with? ssh? git?

Comment: I am using ssh protocol to communicate with the remote git.

Comment: Take a look at @michas answer below; he's taking you down the path I was going to when you responded.

Answer (score 1):

git generally operates using ssh key authentication rather than password authentication.  You'll want to ensure that your repository has your SSH public key on the remote server, in order to properly authenticate using keys.

Comment: IMHO, While it answers the letter of his question (what password is it asking for); I don't think this answers the intent at all (how do i fix the problem).  It certainly doesn't provide anything beyond the question I left for OP in comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asked for a password you are very likely not using ssh keys for authentication.

First make sure you are using the correct URL. Verify that you are indeed using a ssh URL and that username and port number is correct.

Next load your private key into your agent: `ssh-add $private_key_file`

Now verify the key is loaded and show you public key using: `ssh-add -L`

Check that your server is configured with that public key. Verify that the key shown above matches the one configured at your server.

Now your git command should work without ssh problems.

Comment: This is basically where I was going, and what I said in the comments.